Android Studio Showing Red Lines on Correct Code, but Project Runs Fine (Kotlin or Compose Multiplatform)
I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project, and Android Studio is showing red lines on correct code. However, when I try to run the project, it compiles and runs perfectly fine. This is confusing and frustrating, as it's difficult to determine if there are real issues or just IDE glitches.
I've already tried the following, but not worked:

Deleting the /idea folder and restarting.
Invalidating caches and restarting.

IDE Details:

Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1
Build #AI-242.21829.142.2421.12409432, built on September 25, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3052M
Cores: 8
Registry:

ide.instant.shutdown=false
ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
ide.experimental.ui=true
i18n.locale=
jdk.updater=false
ide.images.show.chessboard=true
terminal.new.ui=true



Additionally, I tried switching to IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, but I encountered another issue: the Logcat isn't displaying any logs there, making it difficult to debug the Android part of my project.

